# Sed use line number in replacement

Tags: sed

Does sed know what line it's on, can it put it in a replacement? I.e. find all occurrences of foo and replace with (x) bar where x is the line number

Comment: Please add sample input and your desired output for that sample input to your question.

Comment: I suggest to use `awk`.

Comment: apart from sample input/output, please add what you've tried as well..

Comment: This question has no code, no sample input, and no expected output and yet it got upvoted and has an answer posted. smh....

Comment: Is the question not clear enough as it is?  If someone can answer the question as written, it doesn't seem to need more explanation.  Stack overflow has an android app.  Sometimes people are typing with their thumbs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sed has a command `=`, which only prints the line number to stdout.

You could use it like this:

```
sed '=' YOURFILE | sed 'N; s/^\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)\(NEEDLE\)/\1\2(\1) REPLACEMENT/; s/^[0-9]\+\n//'
```

Example input file `roses`:

```
Roses are red,
Violets are blue,
sugar is sweet,
And so are you.
```

Example command:

```
sed '=' roses | sed 'N; s/^\([0-9]\+\)\(.*\)\(blue\)/\1\2(\1) violet/; s/^[0-9]\+\n//'
```

Example output:

```
Roses are red,
Violets are (2) violet,
sugar is sweet,
And so are you.
```

---

Of course, this is simpler with AWK:

```
awk '{ gsub(/NEEDLE/,"("NR") REPLACEMENT") } 1' YOURFILE
```

Equivalent example:

```
awk '{ gsub(/blue/,"("NR") violet") } 1' roses
```

Comment: or with variables: `awk -v search="blue" -v replace="violet" '{gsub(search,"(" NR ") "replace); print}' file`